# Get members of a enum/struct with pycparser

Tags: python-3.x, pycparser

I have a simple C program in `test.c`, and I want to get the members of `sample_enum` and `sample_struct` using python with the help of pycparser.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum sample_enum
{
    board1 = 0,
    board2 = 1,
    board3 = 2,
    board4 = 3,
    board5 = 4,
    board6 = 5,
} sample_enum_t;

typedef struct sample_struct {
    uint32_t pd_type1;
    uint32_t pd_type2;
    uint32_t pd_type3;
} sample_struct_t;

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

I get the preprocessing output and save it into `test.txt`.

```
gcc -E -I/path/to/pycparser/utils/fake_libc_include test.c > test.txt
```

Here is my python program:

```
from pycparser import parse_file, c_parser, c_ast

if __name__ == "__main__":

    ast = parse_file(filename='test.txt')
    ast.show(showcoord=True)
```

The ast.show prints a bunch of output, including these:

```
  Typedef: sample_enum_t, [], ['typedef'] (at test.c:11:3)
    TypeDecl: sample_enum_t, [] (at test.c:11:3)
      Enum: sample_enum (at test.c:3:9)
        EnumeratorList:  (at test.c:5:5)
          Enumerator: board1 (at test.c:5:5)
            Constant: int, 0 (at test.c:5:14)
          Enumerator: board2 (at test.c:6:5)
            Constant: int, 1 (at test.c:6:14)
          Enumerator: board3 (at test.c:7:5)
            Constant: int, 2 (at test.c:7:14)
          Enumerator: board4 (at test.c:8:5)
            Constant: int, 3 (at test.c:8:14)
          Enumerator: board5 (at test.c:9:5)
            Constant: int, 4 (at test.c:9:14)
          Enumerator: board6 (at test.c:10:5)
            Constant: int, 5 (at test.c:10:14)

  Typedef: sample_struct_t, [], ['typedef'] (at test.c:17:3)
    TypeDecl: sample_struct_t, [] (at test.c:17:3)
      Struct: sample_struct (at test.c:13:16)
        Decl: pd_type1, [], [], [] (at test.c:14:14)
          TypeDecl: pd_type1, [] (at test.c:14:14)
            IdentifierType: ['uint32_t'] (at test.c:14:5)
        Decl: pd_type2, [], [], [] (at test.c:15:14)
          TypeDecl: pd_type2, [] (at test.c:15:14)
            IdentifierType: ['uint32_t'] (at test.c:15:5)
        Decl: pd_type3, [], [], [] (at test.c:16:14)
          TypeDecl: pd_type3, [] (at test.c:16:14)
            IdentifierType: ['uint32_t'] (at test.c:16:5)
  FuncDef:  (at test.c:20:5)
    Decl: main, [], [], [] (at test.c:20:5)
      FuncDecl:  (at test.c:20:5)
        TypeDecl: main, [] (at test.c:20:5)
          IdentifierType: ['int'] (at test.c:20:1)
    Compound:  (at test.c:20:1)
      Return:  (at test.c:22:5)
        Constant: int, 0 (at test.c:22:12)
```

So my question is, do I need to parse the output and extract the members of enum and struct individually? or there is a built-in method/mechanism inside `pycparser` that could potentially makes my life easier.

Comment: This example from the pycparser repo should help: https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/examples/explore_ast.py